# Does the performance of Firestore transactions change significantly when those transactions are dispatched from within Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

At the moment, I have many `Firebase` functions whose performance I'm not happy with when testing locally. The slowest part of these functions are the `Firestore` transactions, even though they are only relatively short series of gets and sets. Atomizing these series as single transactions and/or batching has not improved the performance sufficiently.

So, before I try any other strategies, I wanted to do some research on the relative performance of transacting with `Firestore` when calling from within a `Cloud Function`, i.e., from within `Google Cloud`, and from without. I haven't found anything that quite answers my question yet. Any recommendations or answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the performance of Firestore transactions change significantly when those transactions are dispatched from within Google Cloud?

Transactions involve a network round trip between the client machine running the SDK code that running the transaction and a the Google Cloud backend that hosts the Firestore data.  It stands to reason that reducing the network latency between those machines will reduce the time it takes to execute the transaction.  The only way to know for sure if there is an improvement in your particular case is the perform some benchmarking.

Your best case scenario likely involves the client and backend in the same Google Cloud region.  So, if you are using a Cloud Function in the same region as your Firestore instance, then that should, in theory, be the best option.  Again, only benchmarking will tell how much of an improvement that will be, if any.  Whether or not that is "significant" is dependent on your benchmark observations (and your expectations of what is "significant").

Comment: I'd like it about 2x faster than it is right now. That'd be around 700 ms - 800 ms off.

Comment: Changing regions to place the store closer to my machine did not make much of a difference. Is there any special perimeter around Firestore that I'd be avoiding?